# How to pass a type parameterized interface to a method?

Tags: java, generics

How should I pass a type parameterized interface to a method because java compiler errors out on following code saying "Can not resolve symbol T" in "callTwoParFunc" method signature!

```
class Test{

    interface TwoParFunc<T>{
        T func(T a, T b);
    }

    public void callTwoParFunc(TwoParFunc<T> f, T a, T b) {
        f.func(a, b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `<T>` parameter to the method signature:

```
public <T> void callTwoParFunc(TwoParFunc<T> f, T a, T b) {
    f.func(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. That was a typo. It already had a name and still gives error about not being able to resolve T!

Comment: @alpal does your existing code have the `<T>` between `public` and `void`?

Comment: I see your point. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the parameter a name

```
public <T> void callTwoParFunc(TwoParFunc<T> param, T a, T b) {
    param.func(a, b);
}
```

Comment: Sorry my bad. That was a typo. It already had a name and still gives error about not being able to resolve T!